# Does a magnetic field disentangle an EPR pair?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, magnetic-fields, epr-experiment

The spins of the both electrons of an EPR pair are undetermined before one conducts a measurement on one of them.
Does a magnetic field determine (set up or down) the spin of one partner of an EPR pair if it moves through it and hence disentangle the pair? Is there a potential measurement process involved like emission of a photon from this electron? (I can't imagine how this could happen because the electron was in an indefinite energy state too) But if so, can the EPR pair stay entangled when making the process unobservable (by example closing the field in a box)?

Answer (score 1):

You measure spin with an *inhomogeneous* magnetic field.

If you originally had a spin state like $|\uparrow\rangle_1|\uparrow\rangle_2+|\downarrow\rangle_1|\downarrow\rangle_2$ then there are also spatial states. Let's describe the spatial state of particle 1 as $|C\rangle_1,$ $|L\rangle_1,$ and $|R\rangle_1,$ for Central (undeflecked), Left (deflected left) and Right (deflected right).

Then the state is actually originally something like $|C\rangle_1|\uparrow\rangle_1|\uparrow\rangle_2+|C\rangle_1|\downarrow\rangle_1|\downarrow\rangle_2$ and inside the inhomogeneous magnetic field it evolves into something like $|L\rangle_1|\uparrow\rangle_1|\uparrow\rangle_2+|R\rangle_1|\downarrow\rangle_1|\downarrow\rangle_2.$

The entanglement isn't destroyed by passing through the inhomogeneous magnetic field so much as that now the spin of the second particle is entangled with the position of the first particle instead of the spin of the first particle.

Now the wavefunctiom has two distinct regions of configuration space where it is nonzero and in each region both the spins have definite eigenvalues that happen to be equal.  You could write the total wavefunction as a sum of two waves that each have support on just one of those two regions. And you can ask how each would evolve if it were the whole wavefunction.

If they evolve to continue to never overlap and in fact start diverging in the positions of even more particles not just in the configuration of particle 1 then eventually it becomes too hard to make them overlap again even if you wanted to and tried super hard.

If that happens then each of those waves acts like a world all to itself. And the configurations of the universe supported by one of them are configurations where the people described by those configurations think they are the whole world.

So the *inhomogeneous* magnetic field just passed the entanglement from a spin spin entanglement to a spin position entanglement. And that doesn't start to feel like a lack of entanglement until the two separated waves start to evolve so that they can't ever overlap again.

It is then that the entanglement is between whole Everett branches between whole worlds and then it is truly gone in an operational sense that you can't detect it again.

Before that you could still get those temporarily not overlapping waves to overlap again and thus detect the entanglement. The entanglement is just getting passed up the chain of decoherence. And the *inhomogeneous* magnetic field was just the start of he process. It most definitely isn't done yet because we could reverse it and send both L and R back to C. And thus detect that both L and R are still there and still real. It is when you can't do that in purpose or on accident that is when the two waves act like two waves in worlds of their own instead of one wave with two distinct regions where it is nonzero.

Comment: I put an answer to the question at the end of the track.
Maybe you want to say the same but I could not follow you exactly because of some unclear moments. The explanation was perplexed and I couldn't get your final decision like yes or no. I make this very clear in my comment below.

Answer (score -1):

Remembering the double slit (where the observation of the electron in one slit destroys the superposition |left slit>+ |right slit>) I am almost convinced that the interaction between  the spin superposition |up>+|down> and the magnetic field if not observed would not lead to destruction in it.

Like in double slit where the superposition is not destroyed even when there is an interaction between the electron and the material where the slits are cut trough. Likewise ...the interaction of the electron in superposition and the magnetic field will not destroy the superposition if not observed.

This a general principle of QM! though  I have not seen it explicitly stated in textbooks among the general axioms (which is  a bad omission).

So I think I answered my own question: the EPR pair will stay connected when one of the partners goes through a magnetic field but one takes all measures to prevent observation of that interaction.

Answer (score -3):

> The spins of the both electrons of an EPR pair are undetermined before one conducts a measurement on one of them.

The state of the two particles is undetermined for us or for the particles? It is without doubt, it is undetermined for us without measurement. Do someone not agree?

A interpretation, that the particles state is determined from the beginning of its pair production - one particle has spin up and the over has spin down - couldn't be forbidden. Not the states, but our unknowledge collapses when the state of a particle was measured.

Be sure, to produce two particles nearly simultaneuos does not mean that they are entangled. To produce entangled particles they have to be produced in the same process. This is what we call pair production. And producing pair particles, it has to be that they couldn't be identical in all numbers. The spin has to be different for example. Not to allow to disturb the particle states over distance and time, that is it, what Zeilinger and others are doing.

So, yes it is easy for you to destroy the entanglement for this two particles. The electron's intrinsic spin is connected to the magnetic dipole moment. If you influence this moment by an external magnetic field, you rotate in space the intrinsic spin too and destroy the entanglement.

Comment: Orthodox QM (Copenhagen) insists that the electron is objectively with undefined spin. And only a measurement can set it up or down an specified axis. But the presence of the magnetic field itself is not a measurement. Or it is?

Comment: @Mercury You say it. Some interpretation insist a possibility of something. And yes, the external magnetic field is not a measurement. Although the two electrons have opposite spin, their spin directions are x and x+180° (x is any angle between 0° and 360°). So the magnetic field deflect the electron but the uncertainty does not vanish.

Comment: I put an answer to my own question - answer 3.

Comment: The experiments of Aspect about the Bell s inequalities show that the spin is undetermined, e.g. in a superposition state up + down and this is independent of anyone's knowledge. Read my answer 3.

Comment: if one considers that many technologies derivated from the entanglement theory failed in production ( useful teleportation, quantum cryptology ) , he must conclude that something is wrong. Quantum cryptology doesn't work, it's a fact.